# scanf data from a file and pass to struct

Tags: c

I'm trying to take a data from a file and store it in a struct. I use a string called `buffer` to get all text, and then I use a string called `one_line` to pass the data to the struct.

I added some explation in the code notes.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#define N 10000
#define line 30
typedef struct player
{
    char full_name[N];
    int year[N];
    char team_name[N];
} player;

void main()
{
    char buffer[1000];//string to store all data from afile
    char one_line[line];//string for a struct that take each line separate
    player p[500];//array of struct
    FILE *ptr;//pointer to file
    int i=0,count_of_player=0;
    ptr=fopen("player of the year.txt","r");
    if(ptr==NULL)
    {
        printf("cant open ");
        return;
    }
    while (fgets(buffer,N,ptr)!=NULL)//the buffer get all the text
    {
        while (one_line!='\0')//the string get one line in a time 
        {
            fscanf(ptr,"%d %s %s",&(p[i].year),&(p[i].full_name),&(p[i].team_name));\\get date from file to struct
            i++;
            count_of_player++;
        }
    }
    fclose(ptr);
    while (buffer!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%s",buffer);
    }
    for (i=0;i<count_of_player;i++)
    {
        printf("%s won the best player trophy in %d at the team:%s",p[i].full_name,p[i].year,p[i].team_name);
    }
}
```

Comment: i dont get error but when i try to print the struct i get nothing

Comment: The code you show won't compile. Also, `while (one_line != '\0')` is always true (since `one_line` refers to the address of the array you declared). In addition, the block for the loop never changes the contents of your `one_line` array, so nothing would change the condition if it were referring to any of those contents.

Comment: ok, what i need to change ?

Comment: What is exactly your question? You did not ask any. Please describe the current error. And, first of all, can your code really be compiled?